# c: passing by reference double first pointer stays 0

Tags: c

For some reason the double pointer reference of the first parameters stays always 0, aldough it seems correct for the second parameter. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
unsigned short GetData(unsigned char **pbAdr1, unsigned char **pbAdr2)
{
    printf("Data1: %x", par); //displays 6957f0 ==> OK
    *pbAdr1 = (unsigned char*)par;
    *pbAdr2 = (unsigned char*)par;
    printf("Data2: %x, %x", *pbAdr1, *pbAdr2 ); //displays 0, 6957f0 ==> why 0 for *pbAdr1?
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us [mcve]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*pbAdr1` is a pointer. You are providing a pointer to the `%x` argument for `printf` which is expecting `unsigned int` and is *undefined behaviour*. The code might "work" if the sizeof of a pointer is the same as the size of an `int` but not if they are different.

I suggest you use the proper format specifer

```
printf("Data1: %p", (void*)par);
// . . .
printf("Data2: %p, %p", (void*)*pbAdr1, (void*)*pbAdr2 );
```

Comment: So what exactly happens? Is the first argument overridden by the highest bits of the second argument (because arguments are expected to have size 4, but they actually have size 8 and overlap)?

Comment: Something like that I suppose. Sometimes it can be worth analysing the result of UB if there was a side effect bug somewhere else, to be satisfied that it really was being caused by an error, but it is usually best to move on.

Comment: Note that my compiler issued warnings for your posted code.

Comment: Did some extra debugging: @dyukha: you are correct, there was a type mismatch that caused 4 bytes overlap. Thanks!